# finding a maximum of 10 variables using proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am using a proc sql query to extract id and marks of 5 subjects. I would like to create a new column as maximum marks for that id. i tried to use the below query. but it is giving syntax error.

```
proc sql;
select id, m1, m2,m3,m4,m5, max(m1-m5) as max_marks from data1;
quit;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `largest()`:

```
proc sql;
    select id, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5,
           largest(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5) as max_marks
    from data1;
quit;
```

If not in `proc sql`, you can definitely do this with a data step.

Comment: In SAS the `LARGEST()` function requires another parameter. `MAX(m1,m2,m3)` is the same as `LARGEST(1,m1,m2,m3)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon points out, it's easier if you post the syntax error you're getting. The syntax in your post is correct, but what it is doing is subtracting m5 from m1 and taking the max of that 1 value, clearly not what is wanted.

To get the maximum value across variables using the shortcut `-` then you need to add the keyword `of`.

`max(of m1-m5)`

*** note that this method only works in a data step, not using `proc sql` ***

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for passing a variable list to a function is wrong. To pass a variable list to a function in SAS you need to use the `of` keyword.  `MAX(of m1-m5)`.

Your code is actually calculating the difference between M1 and M5 and since MAX() only has one parameter SAS sees this as a call to the SQL aggregate function `MAX()` and not a call to the SAS function `MAX(,)` for finding the max of two or more numbers.

But **you cannot use variable lists in PROC SQL**, so you will need to list the individual variables.

```
proc sql;
select id,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5
     , max(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5) as max_marks
from data1
;
quit;
```